# Making an error exception when user inputted an invalid entry by giving a message to allow the user to try again

Tags: java, exception

the program suppose to convert the user inputted 24 hour format time to a 12 hour and if the the input is valid. It should send a message saying "the input is invalid, Try again" and the program should revert back to the input prompt.

```
public class TimeFormatException {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inputTime = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String time ;
    char stopper;

    do {            
      System.out.println("Enter time in 24-hour notation: ");
      time= inputTime.nextLine();       
      SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");      
      DateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");      
      Date nullTime= null;
      String outputTime= null;  
      timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
      try {
        nullTime= timeFormat.parse(time);     
        outputTime= timeFormatter.format(nullTime);
      } catch (ParseException ex) {   
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("That is the same as "+ outputTime);   
      System.out.println("Again (y/n)");    
      Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
      stopper = i.next().charAt(0); 
    } while (stopper == 'y' || stopper == 'Y');
  }
}
```

--

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2"
That is the same as null
Again (y/n)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at TimeFormatException.main(TimeFormatException.java:39)
```

Comment: `continue` inside the `catch`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `continue` inside the `catch` block.

```
try {
   nullTime= timeFormat.parse(time);     
   outputTime= timeFormatter.format(nullTime);
} catch (ParseException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace();
    continue;
}
```

This will cause the loop to start from the beginning.

You may want to avoid printing a stack trace and print a user-friendly message instead

```
try {
   nullTime= timeFormat.parse(time);     
   outputTime= timeFormatter.format(nullTime);
} catch (ParseException ex) { 
    System.out.println("The time is not in the expected format");
    continue;
}
```